# Button visibility issue on fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, visibility

I'm learning Android, and have come across a problem with Fragments. I have a simple project that has two buttons and a "fragment place holder" in the main activity. I have added two fragments to the project. When button1 is pressed, the fragment1 is loaded into the fragment place holder. When button two is pressed, fragment2 is loaded into the fragment place holder.

The problem I have is that when I add a button to fragment1, the button is still visible when I pressed button2 to fill the fragment place holder with fragment2. This does not happen to other views (like checkboxes or plaintext editor).

Is there some trick required to make sure a button belongs to a fragment and is only displayed when that fragment is visible?

Here's my layout for fragment1:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="layout.FragmentOne">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_fragment_one"
        android:background="#75e300"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here's my layout for fragment2:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             tools:context="layout.FragmentTwo">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_fragment_two"
        android:background="#cc2525"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here's the layout for my main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="fragmentexample.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment1"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="ChangeFragment"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="ChangeFragment"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
    android:name="layout.FragmentOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_two"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is how I'm changing fragments:

```
  public void ChangeFragment(View view)
  {
    Fragment fragment =
      (view == findViewById(R.id.button)) ? new FragmentOne() : new FragmentTwo();

    getSupportFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment)
      .commit();
  }
```

I just cannot figure out why button3 is always visible. I am expecting it to not be visible when I switch to fragment2, but it's still visible.

Comment: == does not work the way you think.

Comment: Use view.getId() to compare. FindViewById is a waste.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - see my comment below to Samuel Robert. This is a ternary assignment, and does work the way I think. Assigning a value to 'fragment' is not the problem.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot how that is shown on the screen?

Comment: Is it possible that you set the fragment1 xml layout to fragment2? Because I don't see any problem with your java code.

Comment: @SamuelRobert - I'm at work right now so cannot post a screenshot (will be able to do this after work). I don't think its possible I set fragment1.xml layout to fragment2, because the "Fragment1" and "Fragment2" buttons do change the fragments displayed in the "fragment_place" (the fragment container in the main activity). I'll try starting a new project when I get home and will start from scratch.

Comment: Try using hide() and add() methods to replace a fragment

Comment: @ScottDeagan == is NOT assignment

Comment: Also there is no such thing as " ternary assignment". I think you mean the ternary operator. Again, you need to learn how == works.

Comment: Yes, I mean Ternary "Operator". This doesn't change my point - that being the usage in the example I have given is correct. Are you saying that using: `Fragment fragment = (view == findViewById(R.id.button)) ? new FragmentOne() : new FragmentTwo();` is incorrect? If so, please explain why. Otherwise, please do not continue down this path as I'm sure it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late to answer it but still who are looking for answer:

Wrap button and other elements in another layout, like for above problem do the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="fragmentexample.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="ChangeFragment"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Fragment2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="ChangeFragment"/>
 </LinearLayout>
<fragment
android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
android:name="layout.FragmentOne"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_two"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem, but only with buttons, the other elements of my view are not showing. So what i did is to put the button inside a layout, and its working. I don't know if it is a good solution.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/loginConfirmPassEditText">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/singUpBtn"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are including the fragment as part of the XML layout. Android documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout  states the following;

> Note: When you add a fragment to an activity layout by defining the fragment in the layout XML file, you cannot remove the fragment at runtime. If you plan to swap your fragments in and out during user interaction, you must add the fragment to the activity when the activity first starts, as shown in [Build a flexible UI](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui)

So change the `fragment` in the XML to a `View`, and use the `FragmentManager` to add fragment1 to it.

Comment: How does setting the background change anything? Why is hiding the problem a better solution than fixing the actual issue?

Comment: @lionscribe - I have tried setting the background color of FragmentOne and FragmentTwo - it makes no difference, button3 is still always visible.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I believe the changing the background colors was suggested as a debugging technique. The colors make it clear which fragment is displayed. Perhaps the second fragment is not loaded at all.